# Change Dataset in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, python-dataset

I have a dataset like this

```
index  data                    data_list                    label
A      i love pyhton.          ['i love python.',           [1,0] 
       pyhton very useful.      'python very useful.']
B      i like tea. tea         ['i like tea.','tea          [0,1]
       make me happy.            make me happy.']
```

I want to arrange the dataset like below

```
index  data                    data_list                    label
A      i love pyhton.          i love python.               1 
       pyhton very useful.               
A      i love pyhton.          python very useful.          0
       pyhton very useful.      
B      i like tea. tea         i like tea.                  0
       make me happy.            
B      i like tea. tea         tea make me happy.           1 
       make me happy.
```

But, i don't know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help, please. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something called, explode function.Which basically expands, the interable and creates a base index to which grouped by element row. Just do the following line of code.

```
df.explode(['data_list','label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pandas.DataFrame.explode`. Docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

Comment: that should be a comment. I bet it won't take you too long to get sufficient rep.

Comment: Yes, I agree it should be a comment, but I wanted to help and at that moment I don't have enough rep. Sorry for the noise :)